# How to tell WinMerge to ignore binary files in folder compare?

Tags: diff, winmerge

Is it possible to make WinMerge ignore binary files and do only text files comparison when comparing folders?

Answer (score 2):

Winmerge does not detect file structures to check if they are text or binaries. However, you can create filters based on filenames or extensions to ignore certain files.

[image: Using filters]

Comment: Thanks. I already created a filter file that handles many of the IDE intermediate and output files. The problem is that there tend to be lots of binary files w/o a specific extension, and even those w/ extension are too many, so I am searching for a setting that will let e ignore these files categorically.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify file extensions to compare this will make your compare easy.Or create a file filter. Here is the [link](http://manual.winmerge.org/Filters.html).

Comment: Thanks. See my comment to MFT's answer.

Comment: You can specify multiple extensions to compare files, because they are limited. Rather than excluding bunch of files with and without extensions. This is how create my rules.

`def: exclude

f: \.cfm$
f: \.cfc$
f: \.css$
f: \.js$
d: \\*$`