# How to compare 2 folders in winmerge, but ignore file extension?

Tags: winmerge

I think the right regex, forgive my ignorance on this.

I got some ideas from this useful [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772336/how-to-tell-winmerge-to-ignore-binary-files-in-folder-compare) and the [winmerge filter help page](https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Filters.html)

But I can't get it to work. Some help please, much appreciated.

```
f: *\.insv(.mp4)?$ ## *.insv and *.mp4 files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude both extensions in the same filter you can use:

```
f: .*(\.insv|\.mp4)$
```

Or you can use one line to exclude each extension:

```
f: .*\.insv$
f: .*\.mp4$
```